# How to add item to lineItems in checkout.liquid - Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify

I had several trials to add item to lineItems in `checkout.liquid`
I believed this codebase will help my work but it doesn't work in Shopify plus plan.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      var variantId = 7387208286253;
      jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', {
        quantity: 1,
        id: variantId
      });
      setTimeout( 
        function() {
          window.location.reload(true);
        }, 1000);
  });
</script>
```

The codebase above comes from https://dylanjh.com/blogs/22-add-a-free-item-to-checkout-automatically-if-price-over-100-shopify 
And I saw that wonderful feedbacks from the others.
Please lead me the right way. 
Thank you.

Comment: What error do you have? What happens? What is the http response of that call?

Comment: response is 200 OK. but it doesn't show the updated lineItems which include the new item I added through the above API.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use that code before checkout. As you probably know, even Shopify Plus scripting cannot add items to checkout in checkout, meaning you would be running into the same issue trying to use JS. As a side note, you can now easily alter checkout and add free items in a more "professional" way by using Shopify API codes to alter checkout using their App pattern **Post Checkout**. This is probably the best choice I can think of for your use case as of 2022.